# Creating org-time-stamp on new line

Tags: org-agenda

When I use the org-schedule function the time stamp is inserted below the line it was called from. However, when I call org-time-stamp it is inserted where the cursor is, often being inserted between the last letter and the rest of the word. Is there a way I can make org-time-stamp insert itself on the next line, like org-schedule does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`org-time-stamp` inserts **at point** (see definition of `point` in the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Point.html#Point)) so you are in complete control of where the string is inserted. If it is not inserted where you expect, then you need to move `point` (i.e. your cursor) to the appropriate place. Note that `point` is *between* two characters: the character that your cursor is on and the character *before* it.

`org-time-stamp` is also used by other functions (e.g. `org-schedule`) to insert the time stamp, so it does not insert anything extra: if anything extra needs to be added, it is added by the caller either manually or using PRE and POST arguments of `org-insert-time-stamp`, depending where you want to insert the strings.

You can define your own function to make it do what you want, e.g.:

```el
(defun my/org-time-stamp-on-new-line ()
   (interactive)
   (end-of-line)
   (insert "\n")
   (org-time-stamp nil))
```

or

```el
(defun my/org-time-stamp-on-new-line ()
   (interactive)
   (end-of-line)
   (org-insert-time-stamp nil nil nil "\n"))
```

If you don't want to change `point`, you can do this:

```el
(defun my/org-time-stamp-on-new-line ()
   (interactive)
   (save-excursion
      (end-of-line)
      (org-insert-time-stamp nil nil nil "\n")))
```

You call it with `M-x my/org-time-stamp-on-new-line` or you can bind it to a key e.g.

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c z") #'my/org-time-stamp-on-new-line)
```

Comment: `org-time-stamp` is somehow a smart wrap of lower-level `org-insert-time-stamp` which - to me- seems more suited to this particular case.

Comment: @Muihlinn - maybe so, but it takes a TIME param which has to be specified (or converted from a current time). But I didn't bother with that, because I thought that the OP's basic problem was with the definition of `point`: the fact that he complains that "often" the string ends up where he does not expect it was the basic clue. The rest is more for the sake of completeness: if I *had* to do something like that, how would I do it? And again, the emphasis is more on where the string ends up rather than on what the string is.

Comment: I wasn't particularly happy about your edit, exactly because it obscures that point: the complications of `org-time-stamp` are irrelevant in my view.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to me, as long as org-time-stamp can take the same arguments which remains after your correction of my edit,, something I cannot check right now

Comment: I did not mean to "correct" your edit: it was correct already. I was just changing a typo in the first paragraph, but I went ahead and deleted the `-insert` for unfathomable reasons. My apologies.

Comment: My question is the opposite. How to get org-schedule to insert the time stamp on the same line. :)

Comment: @NickD Everything about my edits was just nitpicking over a minor detail, I'm not concerned about it.

Comment: @RaoulComninos Depending the context the approach could be different, but as jack of all trades, `C-h f RET org-insert-time-stamp` and fake it in your own function.